# Randomly disappearing Multi_select TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, multi-select

Recently I downloaded Multi_select TreeView from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30776). It add an option to select multiple TreeNodes.

I use 3 TabControls with 1 Multi_select TreeView on each Page (created dynamicly). There's an option to drag from the first one and drop on another. I can also add additional TabPage(with TreeViwe on it) on each of TabControls.

Problem is that TreeView (drag source) is randomly disappearing, caused by different actions.
Sometimes it's caused by fast drag and drop from one TabControl to another. Sometimes it disappears after creating new TabPage. It happens every 20-30 times. It's really hard to debug drag and drop actions, especially when it's not happening every time.

Here's my Event Handlers to provide drag and drop.

```
private void Tv_ItemDragSource(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes.Count == 0 || (((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes.Count == 1 && ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes[0] != ((TreeNode)e.Item)))
        {
            ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes.Clear();
            ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes.Add((TreeNode)e.Item);
        }

        foreach (TreeNode i in ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes)
        {
            if (i.Level != 0)  
                return;
        }

        DoDragDrop(((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes, DragDropEffects.Copy);

        ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).EndUpdate();
    }

private void Tv_DragEnterSource(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

private void Tv_DragDropSource(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode rewritten = new TreeNode();
        ArrayList selectNodes = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as ArrayList;

        foreach (TreeNode i in selectNodes)
        {
            rewritten.Text = i.Text;
            ((TreeView)sender).Nodes.Add(rewritten);
            foreach (TreeNode j in i.Nodes)
            {
                rewritten.Nodes.Add(j.Text);
            }
            rewritten = new TreeNode();
        }

        foreach (TreeNode i in ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).Nodes)
        {
            i.BackColor = Color.White;
            i.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }

        selectNodes.Clear();

    }

void tv_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode i in ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).Nodes)
        {
            i.BackColor = Color.White;
            i.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }
        ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).SelectedNodes.Clear();
    }

void tv_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).EndUpdate();
    }


void tv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).BeginUpdate();
    }
```

I've added some changing of TreeNodes colour, because there were problems with selecting different nodes after earlier drag and drop.

Thanks in advance!
Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve problem. As I suspected the problem was in BeginUpdate with no EndUpdate triggered. I've added:

```
((MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectTreeView)sender).EndUpdate();
```

on MouseLeave. Now it works well now.

Have a nice day. :)